# file upload angular js and spring Rest API

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

I have a task to upload documents up to 10 mb. I am using angular.js and spring Rest API. However i have data to be posted with uploaded files.
My code is as below.

```
  $scope.submit=function(mymodel){
            var request = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/myurl/update',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': undefined
        },
        transformRequest: function(data) {
            var formData = new FormData();


            formData.append('mymodel', new Blob([angular.toJson(data.mydata)], {
                type: "application/json"
            }));
            //angular.forEach( $scope.files,function(file){
            formData.append('file', data.file);
            //});
            return formData;
        },
        data: {
            data: mydata,
            file: $scope.files[0]
        }


    }
    $http(request).success(function() {


    }).error(function() {

    });

    }
3. API code


@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = {"multipart/form-data"}) //consumes = {"multipart/form-data"}
public @ResponseBody
void updateExceptionSummary(@RequestPart(value="mymodel") MyModel mymodel ,@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file)
{


}
```

I am getting below error:

```
    org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'mymodel' is not present.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.java:194)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:78)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
```

Can anybody please help
what i found is `json` data posted from request is always empty.

Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryJIRCCmCILVsxKIBc

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mymodel"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: application/json
```

------WebKitFormBoundaryJIRCCmCILVsxKIBc

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="1.png"
Content-Type: image/png
```

Comment: Use `@ModelAttribute Mymodel mymodel` and pass the file in the model itself. 
See this two files [JSP](https://github.com/RawSanj/SOFRepos/blob/master/JamiaNew/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/view/student/add.jsp#L68) and [Controller](https://github.com/RawSanj/SOFRepos/blob/master/JamiaNew/src/main/java/in/jmi/controller/StudentController.java#L86). Now convert the JSP code to angular.

Comment: Thanks Sanjay, But we are not able to use Model attribute here because of few restrictions. I Updated code as below and above error gone. Now i facing another error.

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = {"multipart/form-data"}) //consumes = {"multipart/form-data"}
 public @ResponseBody
 void updateExceptionSummary(@RequestPart(value="data") Mymodel mymodel,@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file)
 {
  
  
 }

Comment: var request={
          method:'POST',
          url:'/ews/exceptionsummary/update',
          headers:{'Content-Type':undefined},
          transformRequest:function (data) {
                 var formData = new FormData();
                
                 formData.append('data', new Blob([angular.toJson(data.data)], {
                     type: 'application/json'
                 }));
            
                  formData.append('file',data.file);
        
                    return formData;
             },
          data:{data:$scope.data,file:$scope.files[0]}
}

Comment: org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'data' is not present.
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.java:194)
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:78)

Comment: Move all this code in the Question as UPDATE. Its hard to read in the comments. Also if possible share the minimal working project in github.